# ORA-00838 error after increasing MEMORY_TARGET

Tags: oracle

I've increased *MEMORY_TARGET* in pfile and then create *spfile*. I'm getting the same problem as before:

```
ORA-00838: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET is too small, needs to be at least 3084M
```

The memory_target in pfile is 3084M.

I've already increased `tmpfs` on `/dev/shm` to 5Gb. And no idea what to do next?

Comment: Can you give us the following information in your question: "show parameter memory", "show parameter target", the output from "df /dev/shm", the exact command you run to start up your instance, the output from this... in short, anything more than what you've given.

Comment: Also, are you running a RAC database?

Answer (score 2):

Set MEMORY_TARGET to at least the recommended value.

```
SQL> CREATE PFILE FROM SPFILE;
MANUALLY EDIT PFILE & CORRECT MEMORY_TARGET VALUE
SQL> CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE;
SQL> STARTUP
```

What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter MEMORY_TARGET is for how much physical memory Oracle can use on your machine hosting the Oracle instance; increasing `tmpfs` will not solve the problem; I would suggest setting  `MEMORY_TARGET` to a little higher than the amount suggested by the error message; perhaps set it to

```
MEMORY_TARGET=4G
```

Assuming your machine has over 4 Gigabytes of free memory when Oracle is not runnning!  4 gigabytes is actually pretty small; I would set it higher if your machine (Unix? Windows?) has more free memory available.

Answer (score 0):

check your memory target if your memory target is smaller than the sga_target as defined in the parameter file then you will get the above error. 
My scenario:

I have altered the sga_target using alter database set sga_target=2G scope=spfile
now when I tried to again open the database I was getting the same error.
So I checked my memory_target which was 1G.

So I remove the spfile first and then set my sga_target as 500M and startup the database with pfile and then created spfile from pfile.

Answer (score 0):

If using Oracle 18c XE Database to install the latest version of apex then
Open cmd and then cd to database home directory\bin

```
    cd D:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin
```

Now type the following:

```
    sqlplus / as sysdba
```

If login successful then type the following

```
    create pfile = 'D:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\admin\init.ora' from spfile
```

Open file D:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\admin\init.ora using notepad
Modify value for memory_target=0
Next, type the following

```
    startup pfile = 'D:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\admin\init.ora'
```

Once the database is up type the following script

```
    create spfile from pfile='D:\app\Administrator\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\admin\init.ora'
```

Note: You can use any directory to create the pfile e.g c:\init.ora

Finally Shutdown and restart the database again;
To shutdown type (on sqlplus)

```
    shutdown;
```

To restart  type (on sqlplus)

```
    startup;
```